# std::vector construction with in place construction of elements

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Is it possible to construct a std::vector with an initial size and have it's elements in-place constructed? My stored type is not copyable so this doesn't work because the initial value is constructed as a temporary and copied to the elements:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct A
{
    A(int i = 0) : i_ (i) {};
    int i_;
    std::unique_ptr<int> p_; // not copyable
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> v (10, 1); // error
}
```

This is close to what I'm trying to achieve and maybe it isn't so bad, but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way:

```
int main()
{
    //std::vector<A> v (10, 1); // error

    std::vector<A> v;
    v.reserve (10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        v.emplace_back (1);
    }
}
```

I'm limited to c++11 but I'm interested in c++17 solutions as well out of curiosity.

Comment: Sometimes a plain old loop *is* the cleanest solution.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You can't move an argument more than once

Comment: Agree that your emplace_back version is a good solution.  You could make the first version work by adding a copy-constructor, if that is a sensible feature for your intended use of `A`. (Maybe it could clone the unique_ptr for example)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You can move from `unique_ptr` as many times as you like

Comment: @M.M Your code won't crash but that won't transfer ownership ten times. How could it? The ownership is _unique_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit There's nothing owned by the unique_ptr in this example

Comment: @M.M. If that's the case in the real code then fine, but otherwise you wouldn't want to move-construct your 2nd, 3rd, 4th arguments from the 1st. That's why this feature requires copy-constructibility, as you said yourself.

Comment: in my case the move suggestion isn't terrible as the unique_ptr will always be a nullptr during construction, and I can assert that during construction to avoid misuse...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `std::generate_n`:

```
auto generator = []() {
    return A(1);
};
std::vector<A> v;
v.reserve(10);
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v), 10, generator);
```

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux oh yea. Much nicer :)

Comment: interesting, this works but why doesn't it require the copy constructor? just trying to understand the mechanism...

Comment: @atb it only uses rvalues, so move constructor is used as long as such constructor exists. And your class has implicit move constructor (although the moves may be optimised away by smart compiler).

Answer (score 1):

Your loop solution looks like the best way.

There's no built-in way to create a vector with `N` (for `N>1`) emplace-constructed elements.

Answer (score 1):

When you think that some part of code is to verbose and will appear many times just create a helper function which will be as universal as possible.

The simple version:

```cpp
template<typename F>
auto generate_vector(size_t n, F &&f) -> std::vector<decltype(f())>
{
    std::vector<decltype(f())> result;
    result.reserve(n);
    for (size_t i=0; i<n; ++i)
        result.emplace_back(f());

    return result;
}

// Possible use:
auto v = generate_vector(10, [] { return A(); });
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/ANqIEMBfhIS5Dp60
xor:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename...Args>
auto generate_vector(size_t n, Args&&...args) -> std::vector<T>
{
    std::vector<T> result;
    result.reserve(n);
    for (size_t i=0; i<n; ++i)
        result.emplace_back(args...);

    return result;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/4DHXgRSC9bE9qei9